# Bootbox add spinner icon to button onclick?

Tags: jquery, bootbox

Trying to find a way to add a fa spinner icon to a bootbox dialog button when clicked. Experimenting in the callback changing the fa icon but it changes after the code has executed, see code below. Any suggestions?

```
bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Dialog",
    message: "Text",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: "Cancel",
            className: 'btn-default',
            callback: function(){
            }
        },
        noclose: {
            label: "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> OK",
            className: 'btn-primary',
            callback: function(){
                $("[data-bb-handler='noclose']").find(".fa").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
                //rest of callback code
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but assuming you're using a recent version of Bootbox, then you should be able to add your code to the `onHide` callback:

```js
bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Dialog",
    message: "Text",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: "Cancel",
            className: 'btn-default',
            callback: function(){
            }
        },
        noclose: {
            label: "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> OK",
            className: 'btn-primary',
            callback: function(){
                //rest of callback code
            }
        }
    },
    onHide: function() {
        $("[data-bb-handler='noclose']").find(".fa").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
    }
});
```

This will be called when *anything* closes the modal, though, so not really the ideal solution.

Another possibility is to add an click handler to the your `noclose` button, which you'd want to do in the `onShown` callback:

```js
bootbox.dialog({
    title: "Dialog",
    message: "Text",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: "Cancel",
            className: 'btn-default',
            callback: function(){
            }
        },
        noclose: {
            label: "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> OK",
            className: 'btn-primary',
            callback: function(){
                //rest of callback code
            }
        }
    },
    onShown: function() {
        $("[data-bb-handler='noclose']").on('click', function() {
            $(this).find(".fa").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is add the spinner icon to the button in your callback function. Like this:

```js
let okBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('bootbox-accept')[0]
okBtn.disabled = true
okBtn.innerHTML = '<span class="spinner-border me-1" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>' + okBtn.innerHTML
```